# Color,Price, and Size Filter In PHP Codeigniter And Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter-3

**Section 1**

I have an issue in " Displaying 1 - 5 of 10 records ". I have a piece of code which works only on first page, when i click on second page then it show the same result " Displaying 1 - 5 of 10 records " Instead of " Displaying 10 of 10 records ".

**Code In Controller**

```
 $total=$config["total_rows"];
        $per_page=$config['per_page'];
        $curpage=floor(($this->uri->segment(1)/$config['per_page']) + 1);
        $result_start = ($curpage - 1) * $per_page + 1;
        if ($result_start == 0) $result_start= 1; // *it happens only for the first run*
        $result_end = $result_start+$per_page-1;

        if ($result_end < $per_page)   // happens when records less than per page  
        { $result_end = $per_page; } 
        else if ($result_end > $total)  // happens when result end is greater than total records  
        { $result_end = $total;}
        $data['show']="displaying $result_start to $result_end of $total";
```

I don't know whats wrong with it, I have tried other code which I find from different websites, but they are not working properly.

**Section 2**

I have a filter section, where user can filter product by Size, Color and Price,
How to achieve this section?

**My main/ Index Controller**

```
public function index($page=1)
    {
         $config = array();
         $keyword    = $this->input->post('search');
        if ($keyword === null){ $keyword = $this->session->userdata('search');}
        else{ $this->session->set_userdata('search',$keyword);}
        $config["base_url"] = base_url();
        $config["total_rows"] = $this->crt->total_items($keyword);
        $config['use_page_numbers'] =true;

        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<a class="page-numbers current">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';
        $config["per_page"] =5;
        $config["uri_segment"] = 1;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $page = ($page - 1) * $config['per_page'];
        // showing x to y of z records
        $total=$config["total_rows"];
        $per_page=$config['per_page'];
        $curpage=floor(($this->uri->segment(1)/$config['per_page']) + 1);
        $result_start = ($curpage - 1) * $per_page + 1;
        if ($result_start == 0) $result_start= 1; // *it happens only for the first run*
        $result_end = $result_start+$per_page-1;

        if ($result_end < $per_page)   // happens when records less than per page  
        { $result_end = $per_page; } 
        else if ($result_end > $total)  // happens when result end is greater than total records  
        { $result_end = $total;}
        $data['show']="displaying $result_start to $result_end of $total";
        $data['sidebar']=$this->crt->sidebar_cat();
        $data['products']=$this->crt->get_product($config["per_page"], $page,$keyword);
        $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('index',$data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
```

**My Model**

```
    // Paginitions for Items

      function total_items($keyword)
    {
        //return $this->db->count_all("product");
        $this->db->like('product_name',$keyword);
        $this->db->from('product');
        return $this->db->count_all_results();
    }


      //Fetching Products

    public function get_product($limit,$start,$keyword){
    //    $this->db->where('Is_Hidden',0);
//        $this->db->select('*');
//        $this->db->from('product');
        $this->db->order_by('product_id', 'DESC');
        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        $this->db->like('product_name',$keyword);
        $query = $this->db->get_where('product');
        if(!$query->num_rows()>0)
        {
             echo '<h1>No product available</h1>';
        }
        else
        {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
    }
```

How I can get the Filter section?

**UPDATE 1**

**Section 1** issue has been fixed by replacing those two lines

```
$curpage=floor(($this->uri->segment(1)/$config['per_page']) + 1);
        if ($result_start == 0) $result_start= 1; //
```

**TO**

```
$curpage=$this->uri->segment(1);
        if ($result_start == 0 || $result_start<0) $result_start= 1; //
```

**Update 2**

I somehow did the filter section but now I am stuck in the ajax issue. Issue is that When color or size checkbox is empty then it throw error of foreach loop.
I only need to control the empty or null section, like if the checkbox is unchecked then it will not send / post the value to the controller...

My Ajax Code is

```
function clr(){
           var selected = new Array();
           var size = new Array();
           var url="<?php echo base_url('Cart/filt_color');?>";
          // alert(url);
              $("input:checkbox[name=color]:checked").each(function() {
                  selected.push($(this).val());
                  //console.log(selected);
              });
            // Sizes 
             $("input:checkbox[name=size]:checked").each(function() {
                  size.push($(this).val());
                  //console.log(selected);
              });


              $.ajax({
                  url:url,
                  method:"post",
                  data:{'colors':selected,'sizes':size},
                  success:function(data)
          {
//            
              //console.log(data);
              $("#mdv").html(data);

          }

              });



      }
```

I have tried many check like, `undefined`, or `==''` or `data.length <-1` etc. The `data.length`  will did some check but i am not able to check the variable separately like, there are two variable I am send in `data: color,size`  **How can I check the variable separately like:**  `if(data.color.length < 0 )` .

Comment: this is not what I am looking for, Please read the question again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answered is [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49877680/ajax-call-repeat-post-data?noredirect=1#comment86840412_49877680), All the details and code are posted in the mentioned link question.

Comment: Please provide the main parts of the answer. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/377503

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize the pagination config try to use the the controller/method in `$config[base_url]` and get the page number from `$this->uri->segment(3)`

Comment: but i don't need `$this->uri->segment(3)` i am segmenting it to 1.

Comment: first segment represents the controller, the second represents the method and the others are params

Comment: I set the route accordingly, and segment it to one, and it works perfectly, please read the issue again